Number of 2-connected components in an almost 2-regular 3-uniform hypergraph
Notation: $[n]:=\{1,\ldots, n\}$,  and $\binom{[n]}{k} := \{A \in 2^{[n]}\mid |A| = k\}$ for $k \in [n]$.
Let $M$ be a perfect matching on an even number of vertices $n$, and let $\mathbb{S}_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ vertices. We can construct an almost $k$-regular graph $G_k := ([n], E)$ using $k$ randomly permuted perfect matchings, i.e., we take uniformly at random  $k$ permutations from $\mathbb{S}_n$, $\{\pi_i\}_{i=1}^k$, and apply them to the perfect matching $M$ getting the edge set
$E_k := \bigcup_{i=1}^k \pi_i(M)$.
Say, we would like to compute the expectation on the number of connected components in $G_k$. For $k=1$, it is obviously $n/2$. For $k \geq 3$, we know that the graph is connected with high probability as $n$ goes to infinity (the proof is based on counting the number of empty cuts).
The border case of $k=2$ can be reduced to the noodle problem getting us $O(\log n)$.
My question is, can we compute the same number for 3-uniform hypergraphs, where all hyperedges have size 3? More precisely,$X = ([n], E)$  is a 3-uniform hypergraph  if  $E \subseteq \binom{[n]}{3}$.  For simplicity we will call these hyperedges "triangles".
We say that $X$ is 2-hypergraph connected if for every two pairs $\{x_1,x_2\}, \{y_1,y_2\} \in \binom{[n]}{2}$. There is a sequence of triangle $t_0,\ldots,t_m \in \binom{[n]}{2}$ such that $\{x_1,x_2\} \subseteq t_0$,  $\{y_1,y_2\} \subseteq t_m$ and for each $i \in [m]$ it holds that $|t_{i-1}\cap t_i|=2$.
To generate an almost $k$- regular 3-uniform hypergraph, we use multiple permutations of Steiner Triple Systems (STS) $S \subseteq \binom{[n]}{3}$ on $n$ elements instead of a perfect matching.  By definition STS is a set of triangles such that each pair of elements is contained in exactly one triangle. It is easy to compute that $n$ must be of the form $6m+1$ or $6m + 3$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$. The existence of STS follows from Bose and Skolem constructions.
To construct an almost k-regular 3-uniform $X$, we chose uniformly at random $k$ permutations $\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_k \in \mathbb{S}_n$, and look at the following edge set
$$
E = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}\pi_{i}(S).
$$
Note that by definition of STS, each pair belongs to at least one triangle. Thus, we say that a connected component is trivial if it is an isolated triangle, i.e., $e \in E$ is isolated if for no $e' \in E$ holds $|e\cap e'| = 2.
It is quite easy to compute the expectation on the number of trivial connected components in $X$.
Note that for a permutation $\pi_i$ by the symmetry argument the probability to choose a triangle $t \in \binom{[n]}{3}$ is $\frac{1}{n-2}$, and we want all permutation to pick the same triangle, thus,
$$\mathbb{E}[\mbox{number of isolated triangles in } X] = \binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{(n-2)^k}$$.
Question: an almost k-regular 3-uniform hypergraph $X$ using only two permutations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, how many non-trivial 2-connected components will it have?
The experiments that I ran show that this number is really close to 1 even for small $n$'s, however, I don't see how to prove it. Any help?
